# Input shows previous value, after setting value

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a form with yandex maps integration. I need the value of input to be changed after user picks some point on map. Here is code:

```
function setPlace(c){
    //c - coordinates
    var geocoder = ymaps.geocode(c, {kind: "locality"});
    geocoder.then(function(res){
        var city = res.geoObjects.get(0).properties.get("name");
        var inpCity = document.getElementById(idCity);
        inpCity.value = city;   
    });
}
```

So the problem is I am setting value of input properly (checked in console). But on the page input always shows previous chosen value.

Comment: Have you tried `inpCity.setAttribute("value", city);`?

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle which reproduces the problem so we can try to figure out what's going wrong? It might be about your html, or the `idCity` variable. It's impossible to tell from just this function.

Comment: where do you set idCity?

Comment: in global scope, while assigning all variables. It stores id value. I tried calling `document.getElementById(idCity).value` from console, it shows proper value, but on the page input holds previous value.

Comment: Using `console.log` or `alert`, can you confirm that `idCity` is what you think it is inside your callback? Sorry to be _that guy_, but this is why global variables should be avoided.